# Learn BOM in Javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend

I am a beginner in javascript , now I'm learning a BOM but when I used method `moveTo()`
it can't work I need `moveto(0,200)` childPage after open by button , please help me and explain me where is the problem in it ?

parent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Bom</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="openChild" onclick="openChild()" />
    <input type="button" value="moveChild" onclick="moveToo()" />

    <script src="js/parent.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

parent.js

```
function openChild() {
  res = open("./child.html", "", "width=200 , height=200");
}

function moveToo() {
  moveTo(0, 200);
}
```

child.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      body {
        background: yellow;
      }
      h1 {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <title>child</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>welcome in child</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is BOM???? Did you mean DOM?

Comment: I don't recognise the acronym BOM (other than as Byte Order Mark). Do you mean DOM?

Comment: `moveTo` is that supposed to point at the pop up window? You have no reference to that window. `res.moveTo()`

Comment: BOM ... Browser Object Model?

Comment: yes Browser Object Model